# how to setup gcloud api in windows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-vision, video-intelligence-api

I am new to gcloud, I want to create my first gcloud vision and video intelligence project but do not know how to start and what are the pre-requisite for this. I have Windows 10 laptop and also created my goggle cloud account. Can you please guide my on setup work and how to start development work.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question is too broad. Check [what to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, your effort needs to come before asking the question. The answers you seek are documented online.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites: a Google Cloud Platform project with the [Video Intelligence API](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/before-you-begin) and [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/before-you-begin) both enabled. The APIs are the interfaces between you / your applications and the Cloud services. There are multiple options to access the APIs:

One option is to install the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#windows) on your machine and [initializing it](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing) - linking it with your project.

Afterwards, the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/), which

> is a set of tools for Cloud Platform. It contains gcloud, gsutil, and bq, which you can use to access Google Compute Engine, Google Cloud Storage, Google BigQuery, and other products and services from the command-line. You can run these tools interactively or in your automated scripts.

has the proper (command-line) tools to access [the Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/ml/vision/) and [the Google Cloud Video Intelligence](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml/video/) products.

---

Another option is to make direct calls to the APIs, i.e. via the REST endpoints. You can read about Cloud Vision APIs [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/apis), Video Intelligence APIs [here](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/apis) and test them via [Google's API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/).